# Integration WSO2 Governance Registry with Jenkins

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

How can I do the integration of WSO2 GREG with Jenkins?, I was looking for some tutorial or information about this topic on the oficial page, but there is no documentation, so, I don't know if I have to pay for  support or something similar.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Explain your requirement further.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://dzone.com/articles/application-governance-wso2
any finding that you like to share?